# Regex preg_match to neutralize a pricelist, keeping only digits, dots and commas*

Tags: regex, preg-match

I am using [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) (PHP version 5.5.*) and want to **ignore** all alphabetic letters [a-zA-Z] and special symbols such as `$` and `-`, only to match numbers, commas, dots. Whitespaces between numbers such as `6 000` should be matched. Commas after a number that is not followed by another number should be **ignored**, such as `6,` would only match `6`

Note that this is used in a single string and never in a list, like the sample below. I use the list to show what input and desired output is, "per line".

Sample input:

```
1
1,99
1.99
10
100
5999 dollars
2 USD
$2,99
Our price 2.99
Price: $ 20
200 $
20,-
6 999 USD
```

Desired output:

```
1
1,99
1.99
10
100
5999
2
2,99
2.99
20
200
20
6 999
```

I have tried `/([0-9.,\s]+)/` but the output of `6 999 USD` becomes `6`.

### Edit

The code we are using looks like this:

```
preg_match($regex, $value, $extractions);
array_shift($extractions);
$this->persist($extractions);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/QtRoQC)

Comment: Show us all the PHP code that you're running, not just the regex.

Comment: for me `preg_match("/([0-9.,\s]+)/", "6 999 USD", $m); echo $m[0];` results in `6 999`, php 5.4.7

Comment: @kirilloid Hello, I'm the developer of the code LiuKang is working with. The reason you get a different output from LiuKang is that the code only extrakts the parts that are grouped. So the first match is excluded from the result he can see. So $m[0] is the only part of the matched array we don't use..

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

If you have `&#160;` instead of spaces, you can do two things..my recommended is to just do a `str_replace()` first:

```
str_replace('&#160;', ' ', $number);
```

The other option is to also check for `&#160;` with the `[\s,]` group:

```
[\d.](?:[\d.]|(?:[\s,]|&#160;)(?=\d))*
```

---

**Example:**

```
preg_match('/[\d.](?:[\d.]|[\s,](?=\d))*/', $number, $matches);
$number = reset($matches);
```

**Explanation:**

So I classified the valid characters (digits, spaces, commas, and periods) into two groups: `[\d.]` and `[\s,]`.  A number must start with a digit or a period (`$.99` == `.99` != `99`).  Then we use a repeated non-capturing group `(?:...)*` to take care of our alternation and lookahead assertions.  Anytime there is a `[\d.]` we match it with now questions asked.  Otherwise (`|`), it it is a `[\s,]` we assert that it is followed with a digit using a lookahead (`(?=...)`).

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/HDhrDu)

---

**Example:**

```
preg_replace('/\s*[^\d\s,.]+\s*|,(?!\d)/', '', $number);
```

**Explanation:**

`[^\d\s,.]+` will match 1+ characters that are *not* either a digit, whitespace, a comma, or a period.  We put `\s*` on either side to grab any extra whitespace around these unwanted characters (like in "Our price "). The only unwanted character this doesn't match is a trailing comma.  We use an alternation (`|`), then look for a comma, and then make sure that it is not followed by a digit using a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`).

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/rZJtRg)

Comment: Notice I used `preg_replace()` over `preg_match()` since it created a much cleaner expression.

Comment: Sadly, I have not written the PHP code and must use `preg_replace()`

Comment: @Sam +1 for a good answer. Though it won't help in this case. I'm the developer of the code and updated the question with some additional information to how it's used.

Comment: @Sam it seems to have something to do with the fact that we parsed `&#160;` So I'm guessing it's not a whitespace for some reason..

Comment: The `&#160;` has already been parsed when it comes to the regex. The output seem to look like a regular non-breaking-space. I will see if I can get the ascii value.. It's large code base..